Minimum distance between vector and a subspace given a Minkowski norm
Set-up
In my work, I am trying to approximate a vector field $X \in \Gamma(T\mathcal{M})$ over a manifold $\mathcal{M}$ by some $X_\Delta(p) \in \Delta_p$, which is constrained to lie in the subspace $\Delta_p \subset T_p \mathcal{M}$ (corresponding to the distribution $\Delta \subset T\mathcal{M}$). I am trying to use minimal (and sufficiently weak) structure, to be able to define $X_\Delta$.
One option I consider is a Finsler metric $F:T\mathcal{M} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$. A Finsler metric assigns a (weaker kind of) norm for each tangent space (if $F(v) = F(-v)$, then it is precisely a norm). This structure allows me to define
$$ X_{\Delta}(p) := \arg\min_{v \in \Delta_p} F(v - X(p))\,.$$
But I am unsure if this is a useful definition - specifically, if i have enough structure to find a closed form solution for $X_{\Delta}$ given arbitrary $F$ and $X$. To try to answer this question, I looked at a simplified problem. At each tangent space $V = T_p\mathcal{M}$, $F$ restricts to $F: V \rightarrow [0,\infty)$, a so-called Minkowski norm. Picking further a one-dimensional distribution spanned by $A \in V$, the problem reads as follows:
The main problem
Given a vector space $V$ and a Minkowski norm $F:V\rightarrow [0,\infty)$, and letting $A, B \in V$, is there a closed form solution to $$\arg\min_{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}} F(\lambda A-B)\,.$$
As far as it seems to me, the general procedure is to solve (given differentiable $F$) for $\lambda$ in
$\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}F(\lambda A-B) = 0\,,$
to see if this is indeed a minimum. I.e., $\big(\nabla F(\lambda A - B)\big) \cdot A = 0$. That does not yet indicate the existence of a general closed form, but requires solving on a case-by-case basis - I am wondering if more can be done?
PS: of course, a Riemannian metric (i.e., an inner product on $V$) would give enough structure to simply project $B$ onto $A$, which solves the problem. I am trying to get away with less structure, for the sake of generality.
